# Grouping table rows as fieldset

Tags: html, css

I have a form with input elements in . At the bottom of the form I have a group of inputs, say X. I have a "add more" button, on clicking this button, this group of inputs should be appended to the form.
I have done the JS n HTML part. But I was wondering that is there any way to display group of rows as fieldset(outer border and title/legend), This will look better. Or any other way to do it?

Comment: how exactly do you want it? will you please make it a little clear?

Comment: Could you post your JavaScript and HTML? And, ideally, give some idea as to why you want to wrap `tr` elements in a `fieldset`, as opposed to simply grouping `input` elements in a `fieldset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot group table rows using `fieldset` markup, but you can group them using `thead`, `tfoot`, and `tbody` markup. E.g.

```
<table>
    <tr>... (normal row)
    <tr>... (normal row)
  <tbody class=added>
    <tr><td>foo <td>bar
    <tr><td>hello <td>world
  </tbody>    
    <tr>... (normal row)
    <tr>... (normal row)
</table>
```

You can then style it, e.g.

```
tbody.added {
  outline: solid #696 2px;
  outline-radius: 0.4em;
  -moz-outline-radius: 0.4em;
}
```

Comment: All `tr` elements should be contained within a `tbody`; in your posted mark-up the browser will, or should, correct your mark-up in constructing the DOM and wrap those `tr`s *not* contained within the `tbody` within another `tbody`. [Demonstration at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LykDQ/), check the DOM with 'inspect element.'

Comment: @David Thomas, yes in modern HTML interpretations, the “homeless” `tr` elements are treated as belonging to implied `tbody` elements. This does not mean that my markup would be incorrect. It’s just concise and uses explicit `tbody` tags only for the grouping that is needed. But one needs to note that the elements exist even when the tags don’t, so assigning a style to `tbody` (as opposite to the qualified `tbody.added`) would have undesired effects.